# Install and use QWT under Mac OS X

Tags: qt, linker, qwt

I am currently trying to get QWT 6.1.0 running under MAC OS X 10.7.5.
I followed the instructions over here --> http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html
I didn't changed something inside the configuration files.

So everything worked fine, but now I want to use the qwt-libary inside my own Project.
I added the following line to my .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  /Users/userX/Downloads/qwt-6.1.0/src
```

So my Project is now able to find all the header Files.
But I also have to link against the libary. But I dont know how to do so.
I tried using something like this:

```
LIBS  += -L /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib -lqwt
```

But than I get an error called "libary not found for -lqwt".

What I am doing wrong? 
How can I link against the library or how could I import the qwt framework into my project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution.
Here is a step by step guide on how to install QWT 6.1.0 under Mac OS X and get it running inside the QT-Creator :

1. Download the *.tar.bz2* from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt/6.1.0/
2. Extract it where you want, for Example inside your Download-Folder
3. Then change into the directory *qwt-6.1.0*
4. Then you have to locate the qmake command line tool ( you can do so by simply searchng for it inside the Finder.
5. Then qmake the qwt.pro File like **/Applications/QT/5.1.0/clang_64/bin/qmake qwt.pro**
6. make
7. sudo make install
8. Inside your QT Project you have to add the following line to the
   .pro File ***include ( /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/features/qwt.prf ) 
       includes QWT libary into Project***
9. Now you have to create a softlink like this : **sudo ln -s
   /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.framework/qwt /usr/lib/qwt**

Thats it. QWT now should work.

UNDER MAVERICKS:

If you are using Mavericks you have to manually copy the qwt.framework to Libary/Frameworks folder for not getting the "dyld: Library not loaded: libqwt.6.dylib" error .. i dont know why but it works.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the .tar.bz2 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt/6.1.4/)
2. Extract it where you want, for Example inside your Download-Folder
3. Then change into the directory qwt-6.1.4 (Example: mac:~ Apple$ **cd downloads/qwt-6.1.4**)
4. Then qmake the qwt.pro (Example: mac:~ Apple$ **/Users/(your name)/documents/qt/5.12.5/clang_64/bin/qmake qwt.pro**)
5. mac:~ Apple$ **make**
6. mac:~ Apple$ **sudo make install**
7. Inside your QT Project you have to add the following line to the
   .pro insert this line: **"include ( /usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/features/qwt.prf )**" [without quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVQZI.png)
8. Now you have to create a softlink like this: mac:~ Apple$ **sudo ln -s/usr/local/qwt-6.1.4/lib/qwt.framework/qwt /usr/lib/qwt**

If you have this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt
Referenced from: /Users/Desktop/build-check5-Desktop_Qt_5_12_5_clang_64bit2-Debug/check5.app/Contents/MacOS/check5
Reason: image not found
```

For MacOs Mojave you must copy **qwt.framework** to the **Library/Frameworks** folder.