# qwt 6.1.0 on mac os 10.9 causes : Library not loaded: qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt

Tags: qt

I use qt-creator 5.2 and install qwt6.1.0 on the mac os 10.9. I follow the [guide](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html),and install the qwt6.1.0 success.
I use these cmd:

```
cd $QwtDir
qmake -spec macx-g++
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.framework/qwt /usr/lib/qwt
```

But when I compile the program, It occurs this problem:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt
```

what should I do?

Comment: Same Problem over here. But i didn't found a solution yet.

Comment: The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588418/install-and-use-qwt-under-mac-os-x/58780239#58780239

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the Solution: Just copy the qwt.framework to the Libary/Frameworks Folder and everything should work from now. I was looking for like 3 Hours for finding the right solution after reinstalling everything etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't be possible to manipulate this issue with `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html):

Third-party frameworks can go in a number of different file-system locations, depending on certain factors.

- Most public frameworks should be installed at the local level in /Library/Frameworks.
- If your framework should only be used by a single user, you can install it in the ~/Library/Frameworks subdirectory of the current user; however, this option should be avoided if possible.
- If they are to be used across a local area network, they can be installed in /Network/Library/Frameworks; however, this option should be avoided if possible.

For nearly all cases, installing your frameworks in /Library/Frameworks is the best choice. Frameworks in this location are discovered automatically by the compiler at compile time and the dynamic linker at runtime. Applications that link to frameworks in other directories, such as ~/Library/Frameworks or /Network/Library/Frameworks, must specify the exact path to the framework at build time so that the dynamic linker can find it. If the path changes (as it might for a user home directory), the dynamic linker may be unable to find the framework.